# how to automatcally scale the y-axis in a graph with plotly.net / F#

Tags: f#, plotly

I have a candlestick chart drawn like this

```
Chart.Candlestick(candles |> Array.map (fun x ->
    x.Timestamp, StockData.create x.Open x.High x.Low x.Close))
```

I get:

[image]

When zooming in, I would like the y-axis to automatically scale. Right now, a zoom looks like this:

[image]

I can add:

```
|> Chart.withYAxis (LinearAxis.init(AutoRange = AutoRange.True, FixedRange = false))
```

and then it autoscales when I zoom, but when I scroll afterwards, it doesn't adjust.
furthermore, the thumbnail at the bottom gets scaled as well which doesn't make sense.

It is possible for Plotly.NET to handle this automatically?

Comment: It sounds like this may be an issue that is still in progress to be fixed with Plotly. Found this while poking around:

https://community.plotly.com/t/autorescaling-y-axis-range-when-range-slider-used/12214

It lists the following github issue to improve this behavior: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/1876

Comment: looks like they've given up because no one took the sponsorship request :/